# JS problem with changing the css attribute

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

It's fragment of my PHP code:

```
<div class="log-in">
                                <span>Witaj '.@$_SESSION['user'].' !</span>
                                <div id="img" onclick="reveal()"></div>
                                <ul class="log-in-list">
                                    <li><a href="koszyk.php">Koszyk('.$_SESSION['counter'].')</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="logout.php">Wyloguj się</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
```

And this is a function that should change the opacity of .log-in-list div:

```
function reveal(){
    //console.log('dsbk.kjhdk');
   document.getElementsByClassName("log-in-list")[0].style.opacity = "1";
}
```

And there's a problem. In the console, I see this "script.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'opacity')
at reveal (script.js:14:55)
at HTMLDivElement.onclick (strona-glowna:20:66)".

I tried almost everythig and it didn't work. I expect, tht this function will change opacity of ul with class log-in-list to 1, so it will be visible.

Comment: I ran some tests and the code that you provided works as expected, for testing I just had to set the opacity to 0 by default. There is something else going on that is causing the issue. Like is the HTML displayed to the screen on load or is it don't with ajax?

Comment: code works as expected, did some testing as well

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML? Is `ul.log-in-list` present in the rendered HTML?

Comment: The error message is referring to the `document.getElementsByClassName()` call, saying that it cannot find any element of the class `.log-in-list` at the time the JavaScript method is running. If it's dynamically rendered from the server, it might not exist on page load. Could you confirm if it's there in the DOM? Does the `reveal()` call only run _after_ the `log-in-list` element is added to the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

I see that the problem is in the selector you used in the javascript, you used:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("log-in-list")
```

But this selects an array of elements, but i see that you have only one `.log-in-list` so to fix this, there are two options:

1. Use `getElementByClassName("log-in-list")`
2. Use `querySelector('.log-in-list')`

Both of the options will work perfectly, here's an example using `querySelector()` which i prefer:

```js
function reveal(){
    // Also it's better to use setAttribute('style', '') better than .style method
    document.querySelector(".log-in-list").setAttribute('style' , 'opacity:1 !important;');
}
```

```html
<div class="log-in">
    <div id="img" onclick="reveal()">Reveal Options</div>
    <ul class="log-in-list" style="opacity: 0;">
        <li><a href="koszyk.php">sign up</a></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you have a lot of elements with class `log-in` Then i suggest you using `querySelectorAll()` to select all elements with that class then use `forEach` to select the img of each `log-in` container, and also select `log-in-list` which is also inside the `log-in` container, i'm not sure if you get the idea, but this is the best method i found to explain it hahaha, however here's the code that will make things easier :)

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".log-in").forEach( login => {
    let img = login.querySelector('.img');
    let loginList = login.querySelector('.log-in-list');
    img.addEventListener('click' , ()=> {
        loginList.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:1 !important;')
    })
});
```

```html
<div class="log-in">
    <div class="img">Reveal 1</div>
    <ul class="log-in-list" style="opacity: 0;">
        <li><a href="koszyk.php">sign up</a></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="log-in">
    <div class="img">Reveal 2</div>
    <ul class="log-in-list" style="opacity: 0;">
        <li><a href="koszyk.php">sign up</a></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="log-in">
    <div class="img">Reveal 3</div>
    <ul class="log-in-list" style="opacity: 0;">
        <li><a href="koszyk.php">sign up</a></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```